# MySQL syntax error in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with the stored procedure below? It's telling me there is a syntax error on the IF statement? I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. It works fine if I remove the "create table" statement, and it also works fine if I remove the "IF END IF" statement!

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbo514733022`@`%` PROCEDURE `si_proc1`(IN `param1` INT, IN `param2` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a(ColumnA int);

IF 4 > 3 THEN
    SELECT *
    FROM a;
END IF;
```

Comment: Hmmm.  It is not a stored procedure.  Those usually start with `create procedure`.  In MySQL, the `if` statement needs to be in a stored programming block, such as a stored procedure, stored function, or trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I added the procedure command that mysqladmin is adding for me. I'm doing it through the mysqladmin UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the delimiter to a character apart from the standard `;` since you have multiple statements in your procedure.

MySQL thinks, that your procedure is finished after `create temporary...` statement, therefore the syntax error. Control structures like `if ... then` or `while` are not allowed in usual queries.

Do it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dbo514733022`@`%` PROCEDURE `si_proc1`(IN `param1` INT, IN `param2` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a(ColumnA int);

IF 4 > 3 THEN
    SELECT *
    FROM a;
END IF;
END $$ /*this one ends your procedure*/
DELIMITER ; /*don't forget to change it back to default*/
```

Comment: I think you were right. I managed to get it to work on my own by using just a raw SQL statement in the mysqladmin "SQL" tab instead of using the stored procedure UI. I noticed it wasn't adding the statement to change the delimiters when I used the UI. Perhaps it is a bug or I was missing something. Thanks for your help.